# How to get string between two dot (last dot followed by image extension)?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How to get string between two dot (last dot followed by image extension) ?

I try to filter the string will be delete then replace by '', 
but my regex is wrong, how to solve it?

e.g

```
// a09 could be any letter
var str = 'https://s.domain.com/q1_1-0.a09.jpg';
```

I want to remove `.a09` become

```
'https://s.domain.com/q1_1-0.jpg';
```

try to get .a09  then replace by ''

```
var str = 'https://s.domain.com/q1_1-0.a09.jpg';

var regexPattern = /(\.(.*?)\.(jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$)/;
var removeString = regexPattern.exec(str);
console.log(removeString)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a negated character class to make sure its the last dot before the extensions. Here is a solution specifically for jpg

Replace

```
\.[^.]*(\.jpg)
```

With

```
$1
```

In Javascript dialect:

```
result = subject.replace(/\.[^.]*(\.jpg)/g, "$1");
```

Comment: You know someday I'm going to have to learn regex's..  My solution would have been split & join.. :)

Comment: @Keith if it's any consolation, that solution might been better. A regex is not really needed here.